# Скинуть локальный веб-сайт на Гугл диск

Tags: html, css, wordpress, django

В вузе дали задание написать локальный сайт. Скинуть готовый сайт нужно на Гугл диск. Если написать сайт на Django, wordpress или чём-нибудь другом, как я понимаю, у сайта появляются зависимости от вашего компьютера. У проверяющего может не работать этот веб-сайт. Можно ли как-то решить эту проблему?

Comment: как например делают они - https://github.com/app-generator/django-volt-dashboard

Comment: Если вы сделаете сайт на WordPress и скинете его файлы на гугл диск, то никаких зависимостей с пк не будет, просто нужно будет ещё сохранить БД и потом на другом ПК развернуть при необходимости локальный сервер, перенести файлы сайта, развернуть БД и поменять урлы в БД

Answer (score 0):

так надо у преподавателя уточнять этот вопрос, если не используется БД, а сайт простой на html css js, то откроется в любом браузере если будет правильная структура в папке с сайтом, папку сайтом можно без проблем хоть куда залить, расшарить и дать ссылку на скачивание, наверно это и требуется, вряд ли в институте задают что то очень сложное, если же cms, то конечно тогда нужно локальный веб сервер для запуска типа open server, тут как вариант хостинг бесплатный например на beget, либо залить на github gitlab и дать ссылку на репозиторий с сайтом.
здесь первый вариант самый простой и наверно он и требуется, а вариант с github самый полезный, потому что можно еще прокачать навыки работы с ветками хранилища кода (это в любом случае когда-то придется разбирать) и встроенным редактором кода на основе vscode, это никогда не будет лишним.
вообще тему открывать надо с того, как точно звучит задание